# jQuery and If Statement Not Matching Because of Multiple Classes

Tags: jquery

I have DOM elements I'd like to exclude from a .click function by adding a class "noEdit" the problem I'm having is some of these elements have multiple classes ie:

```
<td class="firstCol noEdit"> // <-- wont work
<td class="noEdit"> // <-- works fine
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('td').click( function(){
    if($(this).attr('class') != "noEdit"){
        alert('do the function');
    });
```

thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you query the `class` attribute with `attr()`, it simply returns the value as a single string. The condition then fails for your first `<td>` because your code will attempt to compare

```
"firstCol noEdit" != "noEdit"
```

Which returns true (since they're not equal) and causes your alert to display.

You'll want to look at the `hasClass()` function instead, which parses the class list for you and checks for the presence of the given class in the attribute:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("noEdit")) {
        alert('do the function');
    }
});
```

Comment: both great answers, I was more looking for this one though, as I can perform another function with my event targets that HAVE the class noEdit.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Jascha: that'd be three great answers; Dave just posted ;)

Answer (score 4):

How about using an attribute filter:

```
// != means 'not exactly matching', whereas *= means 'contains'
$('td[class!=noEdit]').click( function(){
    alert('do the function');
});
```

Comment: That seems much cleaner (the if condition is also no longer necessary since OP just wants to filter stuff depending on only the `noEdit` class). +1

Comment: @Boltclock - Heh, I realise that I left the `if` statement in the answer. How freaking stupid. (fixed now, but...)

Comment: hasClass may be faster though,.... It would be worthwhile to check the speed of this vs. that.

Comment: Excellent.  In this particular case I was looking more for boltclock's reply, but I'm upvoting for awesome tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery's not() traversal](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to clean that up:

```
$('td').not('.noEdit').click(function() {
  alert('do the function');
});
```

Comment: This is viable (and possibly) faster than the two above approaches, as it is using jQuery's list methods rather than the sizzle selector engine thingie. +1

Comment: @karim79: `not()` doesn't use Sizzle? That's interesting!

Comment: @Boltclock - I think that's the case (think !=  know) but I'm too lazy to check at this particular point in time :)

Comment: @karim79: I checked the source: `not()` seems to just call `pushStack()` with a `not` filter with the given selector.